# event color different from each other in fullcalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am working on a fullcalendar, and trying to differentiate the events next to each other. What I am thinking about doing is using two colors and fill in the events one next to it, so no neighbor events have the same color. 
I am not sure how to do this, anyone has experience please share some idea=)

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to do this at the moment?

You will need to set the event td(I presume your using a table) to `active`, then possibly use `nth-child`